# その without a following noun?

Tags: demonstratives

> A: あの～、すみません。
>   B: はい。
>   A: このへんにこうしゅうでんわはありますか。
>   B: こうしゅうでんわですか？
>   A: ええ。
>   B: えーっと...ああ、コンビニのまえにじどうはんばいきがありますね。
>   こうしゅうでんわはそのとなりにありますよ。
>   <sub>[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UL56.png)</sub>

In the sentence こうしゅうでんわはそのとなりにありますよ, why その allowed to not have a noun after it? Shouldn't それ be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of 「この」,「その」and 「あの」 as contractions of 「これの」,「それの」and 「あれの」. In most sentences you could happily swap one for the other. There is a slight difference in emphasis, IMHO.

Comment: 「この」,「その」and 「あの」indicate location/place. How would 「これの」,「それの」and 「あれの」relate to that?!

Comment: @quetzacoatl Are you sure you aren't thinking of ここ, そこ, and あそこ? What would be the location or place in あの男, or このペン? I guess it's also possible you just mean the general relative positions implied by こそあど words, but all of the mentioned ones have that.

Comment: This is an interesting comment, but I don't think it really addresses the OP's confusion with となり following その.  To be clear, they asked why その can be used without a noun after it, but in this case it does have a noun after it as the other answer explains, and you haven't addressed their question.

Answer (score 10):

> こうしゅうでんわは**その**となりにありますよ

「となり」 is a noun; therefore, it is perfectly grammatical and natural-sounding to say 「そのとなり」.

That means that it is not grammatical to say 「それとなり」.

「そのとなり」 in this context refers to 「じどうはんばいきのとなり」 ("right next to the vending machine").  That is where the public phone is located.